# List sorting with bubble sort (list of list)

Tags: python, list, sorting, bubble-sort

I have this assignement where I had to put a text file into a list so it looks like this eventually:

```
[["Afghanistan",647500.0,25500100],["Albania",28748.0,2821977],...,["Zimbabwe",390580.0,12973808]]
```

So a list of lists which is defined by the function readcountries() 
I would like to sort this list with a bubble sort (this is required by the assignement) based on one of the parameters in the list of lists (namely the population which is the second number after the country name).

This is what I have so far

```
def bubblesort():
    Countries = readcountries()
    for i in range(0,len(Countries)):
        madeSwap = False
        for j in range (0,len(Countries)-(i+1)):
            if Countries[j][2] > Countries[j+1][2]:
                temp = Countries[j+1]
                Countries[j+1][2] = Countries[j][2]
                Countries[j] = temp
                madeSwap = True
            if not madeSwap:
                return
```

But I dont get any kind of sorting with this for some reason and I even have trouble seeing the sorted list after.
Any help is welcome

Comment: Well, for starters, you might want to return `Countries`.

Comment: Also, you want to swap the entire entry, not just `[2]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is here `Countries[j+1][2] = Countries[j][2]`
you have to replace with `Countries[j+1] = Countries[j]`

Also

you have to invoke this

```
if not madeSwap:
                return
```

In outer for

And return list

```
def bubblesort():
        Countries = [["Afghanistan",647500.0,3],["Albania",28748.0,1],["Zimbabwe",390580.0,2]]
        for i in range(0,len(Countries)):
            madeSwap = False
            for j in range (0,len(Countries)-(i+1)):
                if Countries[j][2] > Countries[j+1][2]:
                    temp = Countries[j+1]
                    Countries[j+1] = Countries[j]
                    Countries[j] = temp
                    madeSwap = True
            if not madeSwap:
                return Countries
        return Countries

>>> bubblesort()
[['Afghanistan', 647500.0, 1], ['Zimbabwe', 390580.0, 2], ['Albania', 28748.0, 3]]
```